# AS3 | Dynamically assets embedding

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cc

I'm trying to add generic content while embedding my game assets but came up with nothing so far. What I usually do is:

```
public final class AssetsManager 
{
   [Embed(source="../assets/game1/icon.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
   private static const Icon:Class;
}
```

However, I want to do something like this:

```
public final class AssetsManager(gameName:String)
{
   [Embed(source="../assets/"+gameName+"/icon.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
   private static const Icon:Class;
}
```

I'm not able to transfer params via the class, so I believe there's another way.

Comment: I already answered this in your other question.  You need to load content dynamically at runtime, OR use a compiler constant and make different versions of the swf file based off the directory value.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding happens at compile-time so this isn't possible. Instead, you can load in assets at runtime, for example using a `URLLoader` as a `ByteArray`, or `Loader` as `Bitmap`, or a Flex `Image` control.